# Get list of related values Angularfire 4 Ionic 3

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, angularfire

I am working to calculate the difference between two times in ionic.

I am using AngularFire and my tree looks like this:

```
{
    "users": {
        "name": {
            "17": {
                "10": {
                    "2017": {
                        "-Kwfm1k9_A74PzlmijUJ": {
                            "date": "17/10/2017",
                            "hora": "17:20:58",
                            "status": "In"
                        },
                        "-Kwfm8wEJ8Oob4YFvNNu": {
                            "date": "17/10/2017",
                            "hora": "17:21:27",
                            "status": "Out"
                        },
                        "-KwfoKkPJMt2g8AQNmxq": {
                            "date": "17/10/2017",
                            "hora": "17:31:00",
                            "status": "In"
                        },
                        "-Kwfp0BOAGnM-2_MfziP": {
                            "date": "17/10/2017",
                            "hora": "17:33:58",
                            "status": "Out"
                        },
                        "-KwfqW5XKpUNedda4rZz": {
                            "date": "17/10/2017",
                            "hora": "17:40:31",
                            "status": "In"
                        },
                        "-Kwg0pQDlI3FMV3BPNaa": {
                            "date": "17/10/2017",
                            "hora": "18:29:58",
                            "status": "Out"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to get a difference between the first and second, third and fourth, fifth and sixth, remembering that they are related by the tag "Status".

```
First In - Out = difference
Second In - Out = difference
Third In - Out = difference
```

Always doing the difference between the In's and Out's.

In's are for when a person come in the room. Out's are for when a person come out of the room. I want to record the time a person spend inside of a room.

So the results would be:

```
"17:20:58" - "17:21:27" = 00:01:29
"17:31:00" - "17:33:58" = 00:02:58
"17:40:31" - "18:29:58" = 00:49:27
```

Do you have any tip on refactoring this code so it works fine?

Remembering I'm using Ionic 3 with AngularFire4

Appreciate the help.

Comment: How are the IN and Outs related to each other? Can you describe the use case?

Comment: Thanks man. Edited with better description. check it out: **Out's are for when a person come out of the room. I want to record the time a person spend inside of a room.**

Comment: ok, gotcha. Working on an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal I recommend you to restructure your data. For now, there is no real relation between the IN's and OUT's.

A possible approach would be to create some node which wraps the checkIn and the checkOut. Let's call it `session`. Each time a user checks in a new session get's created and each time a user checks out a session get's closed.

Your structure could look similar to this:

```
"sessions": {
  "uid": {  // or name or whatever
    "17-10-2017": { // not sure if you need the date in the structure, but if you need it make a single node like this
      "-Kwfm1k9_A74PzlmijUJ": { // this is a session create it on each check in
        "checkin": 1508354574, // timestamp
        "checkout": 1508354584
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a code example (just to give you an idea how it could look like):

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("sessions/uid"); // uid must be dynamic

// checkin
ref.push({
  checkin: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP // make sure to use the servers timestamp
}); // creates a new session with a pushkey as id

// checkout
ref.child('sessionId').update({
  checkout: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
});

// stats
ref.child('sessionId').once('value', function(snap) {
  var session = snap.val();
  var difference = session.checkout - session.checkin;

  // now you have the difference in milliseconds or seconds depending on your timestamp format. this can be formatted whatever unit you want e.g. minutes, hours...
});
```

Hope this gives you an idea, how it could be done.